# Encoding: Java Memory Leak

Tags: java

I'm newbie on this site.
 I state my problem and I hope someone can help me.
 I compiled the same class in Java UTF \ 8 and CP1252 (default). The execution of the first class generates memory leaks. A different encoding declaration can create access to memory and then memory leaks?
I state my problem and I hope someone can help me. I filled in the same class in Java UTF \ 8 and CP1252 (default). The execution of the first class generates memory leaks. A different encoding declaration can create access to memory and then memory leaks?

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote "Google says:" and repeated your text..

Comment: You may want to add your code to this post

Answer (score 0):

How can you say you have memory leaks? Note that garbage collector will run when it thinks it will be appropriate, no when you order it to run.

Comment: Java can still have memory leaks.

Comment: On the first run the program went to the exhaustion of memory (1GB). During the second run the program was kept at 70 MB. I then retried the same procedure: the same behavior.

Comment: After the exhaustion you got OutOfMemoryError? Still first guess is code error.

Answer (score 0):

At first: Look which characters you use in your source code. I believe you have non-ascii characters in the source, else there would be no difference in which input encoding you use for your source files.

And IF you use non-ascii characters, you have to stick with one source encoding anyway... else your input files would make no sense.